# How to print Arabic text and QRcode Via CPCL Commands using Zebra Zq220 in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, printing, bluetooth, zebra-printers

I face an issue when I tried to print Arabic text or QRCode using **Zebra ZQ220** via Bluetooth, as the printer prints strange symbols.

I mainly depend on below packages :

- esc_pos_utils: ^1.1.0
- flutter_pos_printer_platform: ^1.0.12

works successfully when printing English, but when printing Arabic or QRcode it prints strange symbols most probably it's an encoding issue.

how to solve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why you dont use ZPL?